# Creating a polymer element from Google Maps JavaScript API v3? (Help needed)

Tags: asynchronous, google-maps-api-3, polymer

Can't seem to get the google maps api loaded in the main page.

page-content.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="gmaps-simplified.html" async>

<polymer-element name="page-content">

    <style>
        :host {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .page-content {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
    <gmaps-simplified ></gmaps-simplified>
<script>
    Polymer({

    });
</script>

</polymer-element>
<page-content></page-content>
```

and the google api, this works on its own.

gmap-simplified.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="gmaps-simplified">
<template>

    <div id="mapCanvas" style="background-color:#73da9c;width: 100%;height: 100%"></div>

</template>
<script>
    Polymer('gmaps-simplified', {

        ready: function () {

            var stylers = [
                {
                    featureType: "water",
                    stylers: [
                        {
                            color: "#73da9c"
                }
]
}, {
                    featureType: "administrative",
                    stylers: [
                        {
                            visibility: "off"
                }
]
}, {
                    featureType: "landscape",
                    elementType: "labels",
                    stylers: [
                        {
                            color: "#808080"
                },
                        {
                            visibility: "off"
                }
]
}, {
                    featureType: "poi",
                    stylers: [
                        {
                            visibility: "off"
                }
]
}, {
                    featureType: "road",
                    stylers: [
                        {
                            visibility: "off"
                }
]
}, {
                    featureType: "transit",
                    stylers: [
                        {
                            visibility: "off"
                }
]
}, {
                    elementType: "labels",
                    stylers: [
                        {
                            visibility: "off"
                }
]
}, {
                    featureType: "landscape",
                    elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                    stylers: [
                        {
                            visibility: "off"
                }
]
}, {
                    featureType: "landscape",
                    elementType: "geometry",
                    stylers: [
                        {
                            color: "#cff2dd"
                }
]
}
];
            var minZoomLevel = 3;

            var map = new google.maps.Map(this.$.mapCanvas, {
                zoom: minZoomLevel,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(35, 6.852363),
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'custommap']
                }
            });



            var styledMapOptions = {
                name: 'Nick Style'
            };

            var customStyledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
                stylers, styledMapOptions);

            map.mapTypes.set('custommap', customStyledMap);
            map.setMapTypeId('custommap');

            // Limit the zoom level
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
                if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
            });
        }
    });
  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={KEY}">
</script>
</polymer-element>
<gmaps-simplified></gmaps-simplified>
```

I've got the api to work as a custom element. But when I open the page-content.html it will only show the background color of gmaps-simplified.html 
And the console gives the following error messages:

```
ConsoleAgent: Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to      
write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless  
it is explicitly opened. (url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
key={{KEY}}) in getScript:14
```

and:

```
 ConsoleAgent: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (url: 
 http://127.0.0.1:56264/elements/gmaps-simplified.html) in Polymer.ready:29
```

There is an example for '[Asynchronous Loading](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async)' on the api page but I cant get this to work for polymer..

Does someone have any idea on how to achieve this?

Or is the asynchronous loading not the main issue?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Might want to take out the api_key reference from your example ..

Comment: Any reason why you're not using https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map ?

Comment: Removed the key, thanks for noting..! 
I suppose i could try the component but it felt nice and light this way. Plus the api's site is well documented, I want to add more features later on.

Comment: Your key is still in the second stack trace btw ;) Might want to re-generate that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you might have to bring the script tag that loads google maps into the actual body element of the page, or potentially just outside the scope of the polymer-element definition, although this last solution might break when your component is loaded from within another component.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your comment did the trick. Moved the script to the page-content(outside polymer tag) and removed it from the gmaps-simplified and it worked!